# Active Model Serializer, testing which serializer is used to render response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, active-model-serializers

I'm using active model serializers to render JSON responses from a rails controller.

I have a controller action like this:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  if @foo.user == current_user
    render json: @foo, serializer: FooSerializer
  else
    render json: @foo, serializer: TrimmedFooSerializer
  end
end
```

I want to be able to test which serializer has been used in my Rspec controller tests. Is it possible to get a reference to the serializer from the tests?

**UPDATE:**

I don't think this a correct use of the serializer. I now have logic in the serializer itself to conditionally include attributes. The controller shouldn't really care about which serializer to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I am assuming that you are using `factory_girl`. You can write the other test by returning a different user for `current_user`

```
describe "show" do
  it "should use FooSerializer to serialize if the logged in user is the same as params user" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
    FooSerializer.any_instance.should_receive(:to_json).and_return("{\"key\": \"value\"")
    get :show, :id => user.id
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

It has been a while since anyone replied but in case future googlers find this, I like the following approach:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :serialize_object do |object|
  match do |response|
    @serializer_klass.new(object).to_json == response.body
  end

  chain :with do |serializer_klass|
    @serializer_klass = serializer_klass
  end
end
```

Then in your tests you can do:

```
expect(response).to serialize_object(claim).with(ClaimSerializer)
```

Note that I didn't call the matcher 'serialize' because shoulda already defines a matcher of that name.

Comment: very elegant an useful aproach

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate further on [Dan Draper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667774/dan-draper) answer, I found that when using the JsonApi adapter, this is the way to go:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :serialize_resource do |object|
  match do |response|
    serialized_json(object) == response.body
  end

  chain :with do |serializer_klass|
    @serializer_klass = serializer_klass
  end

  failure_message do |response|
    "expected response body #{serialized_json(object)}, got #{response.body}"
  end

  def serialized_json(object)
    serializer = @serializer_klass.new(object)
    adapted = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer)
    adapted.serializable_hash.to_json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I took what [Knightstick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799819/knightstick) did above and improved it a little bit, like for instance, the error message and by adding ability to handle both single resource or a resources collection (I'm using the active_model_serializers gem, version 0.10.0).

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :serialize_resource do |resource|
  match do |response|
    serialized_json(resource) == response.body
  end

  chain :with do |serializer_klass|
    @serializer_klass = serializer_klass
  end

  failure_message do |response|
    "expected response body #{serialized_json(resource).inspect}, got #{response.body.inspect}"
  end

  def serialized_json(resource)
    options = if resource.is_a?(Array)
                { each_serializer: @serializer_klass }
              else
                { serializer: @serializer_klass }
              end

    serializable = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resource, options)
    serializable.serializable_hash.to_json
  end
end
```